# The Nx library performs a strange examination

Tags: nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I keep getting grammar errors in the json file during the build using the "nx format:write" corresponding command. I don't know why I get these errors. I want to build.

```bash
$ nx format:write
.eslintrc.json
[error] .eslintrc.json: SyntaxError: ';' expected. (2:9)
[error]   1 | {
[error] > 2 |   "root": true,
[error]     |         ^
[error]   3 |   "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
[error]   4 |   "plugins": [
[error]   5 |     "@nx",
apps\admin\.eslintrc.json
[error] apps\admin\.eslintrc.json: SyntaxError: ';' expected. (2:12)
[error]   1 | {
[error] > 2 |   "extends": [
[error]     |            ^
[error]   3 |     "plugin:@nx/react-typescript",
[error]   4 |     "next",
[error]   5 |     "next/core-web-vitals",
```

Excluding it with lint settings or pretier settings doesn't seem like a solution. Please advise.